# I used WUBI to install Ubuntu to the external hard drive, but when I reboot it shows only windows xp

Tags: installation, grub2, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When I boot I do not get asked which OS I want](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233961/when-i-boot-i-do-not-get-asked-which-os-i-want)

I have a windows XP computer, wubi was downloaded into my external hard drive, this was the first time that wubi fully downloaded and told  me to reboot, but when I did it automatically went to the windows XP menu screen. Help!?

Comment: Check the `Time to display operating systems`: Right click on `My Computer`, `Properties`, `Advanced` tab, Startup & Recovery settings. It should be set at 10 or larger. Otherwise edit your question and post the contents of the `C:\boot.ini` file.