# When I boot I do not get asked which OS I want

Tags: boot, wubi, windows-xp, bios

I just installed `Wubi` on my computer which is running `Windows XP`. Everything went exactly like [the official guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows) said it should, and I was told the installation was complete and to restart my computer. However when I boot the boot-loader does not appear.

There is a problem with the fan of the computer, and each time I boot I am asked if I wanted to continue, and I have to press `F2` within 5 seconds otherwise the computer shuts down. I do not see a `BIOS` screen for this reason, so I do not know how to get to the `boot menu`.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with `BIOS`. The `boot menu` is the Windows boot manager. Sometimes the edits to the `boot.ini` don't work (XP) or `bcdedit` (Vista/7/8) for unknown reasons. Check the `Time to display operating systems` (most common prob is it's set at zero, make it 10). Or edit your question with the contents.

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in a comment:

> It doesn't have anything to do with *BIOS*. The *boot menu* is the
>   Windows boot manager. Sometimes the edits to the boot.ini don't work
>   (XP) or bcdedit (Vista/7/8) for unknown reasons. Check the `Time to
>   display operating systems` (most common prob is it's set at zero, make
>   it 10). Or edit your question with the contents.

– [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) [Dec 29 '12 at 15:13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233961/when-i-boot-i-do-not-get-asked-which-os-i-want#comment290134_233961)